# Check if an element IS an offsetParent

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Is there a convenient way to check if an HTMLElement *is* an offsetParent?

I have a situation where I need to determine an element's offsetParent *before* it is inserted in the DOM. I can access the element's immediate parent, before insertion.

There doesn't seem to be any properties on HTMLElements that indicate whether or not it *is* an offsetParent.

Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: You can’t determine an element’s offsetParent before it’s inserted in the DOM because it depends on the styles applied to that element. What’s your situation?

Comment: Could you please provide an example code that represent your current situation? Maybe we can suggest an alternative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is to my knowledge unfortunately nothing in the DOM API that does expose this information on the Element itself.

[According to specs](https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom-view/#dom-htmlelement-offsetparent), an *ancestor* can be an `offsetParent` if

> The element is a containing block of absolutely-positioned descendants

This means that not only positioned elements will qualify, but any element with a `transform`, or a `filter`  property, a `will-change` with a value containing any of the aforementioned ones will also do.

However this behavior was not always specified this way, so it may return false positives in some browsers.
Also, it may be that in the future other CSS properties will affect what makes a *containing block*, or even in the present since I only got these from the tip of my head...

With that in mind, the surest is to append a test element inside your element and to check its `offsetParent`.
However, this will create forced reflows, so **use it sporadically**.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.container > div')
  .forEach(elem => {
    elem.textContent = isOffsetParent(elem) ? 'offsetParent' : 'not offsetParent';
  });

function isOffsetParent(elem) {
  const test = document.createElement('span');
  elem.appendChild(test);
  const result = test.offsetParent === elem;
  elem.removeChild(test);
  return result;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="is-offset-parent" style="position:relative"></div>
  <div class="can-be-offset-parent" style="transform:translate(0)"></div>
  <div class="can-be-offset-parent" style="filter:blur(1px)"></div>
  <div class="is-not"></div>

</div>
```

But if you really wish some unsafe way which may need to be updated, then you could check all the properties I mentioned before using `getComputedStyle(elem)`.

Comment: Thank you for `const result = test.offsetParent === elem;` that really helped me fix an issue I was running into with a fixed element being pushed offscreen due to a parent transform.